# MVC, Bootstrap, SQL, Image issues

Tags: sql, image, model-view-controller, bootstrapping

I apologize in advance for my ignorance.  I recently took on an internal website that is having some issues.  The problem is that it is done in MVC and bootstrap and I have no knowledge of these.  When the user clicks a button on the side menu, it is supposed to show containers in the main panel.

One user uploaded a corrupted image.  So now, whenever we try to click on this particular button, it appears that it is still trying to find this entry in the database (id = 571).  However, my id's in the database, do NOT go up to 571, they only go to like 533.  I should mention that the images are saved in the 'contents' table as a byte array.  So it appears that this website is trying to find an entry in the database that does not exist and then it just throws an exception that the image does not exist in the stream and then it will not show the rest of the content in that container.  Here is the code:

```
using( var memoryStream = new MemoryStream( numArray ) )
        using( var img = Image.FromStream( memoryStream ) )
        {
            string str = string.Format( "data:image/{0};base64,{1}", GetImageFormat( img ), Convert.ToBase64String( numArray ) );
            tagBuilder1.MergeAttribute( "alt", altText );
            tagBuilder1.MergeAttribute( "src", str );

            return MvcHtmlString.Create( tagBuilder1.ToString( TagRenderMode.SelfClosing ) );
        }
```

It blows up on the second line:

```
using( var img = Image.FromStream( memoryStream ) )
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction in how to figure out where this image is actually saved, why it's not reading the database correctly, how do I fix this issue, or any hints would be great.  I've debugged for 4 days now and I still am no closer than when I started.  Thanks in advance and again, I apologize for my ignorance.  I am going to fix the ignorance portion very, very soon, but for now, for this 'emergency' on this website, I'm at a loss and running out of time.  Thank you!!

Comment: Have you looked for another query that may join on you contents.id table? I thinks somthing is wrong before this portion of code, you need to find how numArray is pupolated, there must be a query or a table behind that.
I guess that you have delete the corrupted picture 571, but it must still exist as a foreign key of another table. have a look at the the tables that a reference your "contents" table

Comment: @Julien R - Yes, I have looked at all the tables.  The database consists of 5 tables only.  I've looked at these tables multiple times and cannot see anything that is wrong per se in the database.  Basically, there are 3 tables that interact together and none of them have the information for this added content that the user uploaded.  Her normal process is to 'create' the container through the website and add her description, save it, then go back and upload the image.  This container is just NOT in the database anywhere.  I will keep digging through the code to find other queries.  Thank you!